# Tomcat 7: editing port on linux

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, ubuntu, port

Sorry for the possibly dumb question, but I can't seem to find the answer via google..

I just installed tomcat7 on my Linux computer. When I try to run the server, it says "port 80 required is already in use." How do I change the port it runs on? Also, any suggestions on which port to change to, if it matters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check server.xml

Answer (score 3):

1. Locate server.xml in your ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/ directory
2. Find a tag that starts with `<Connector`
3. Change port from 80 to something else like 8080
4. (Re)Start your Tomcat process

For configuring Tomcat 7 please refer: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

PS: To figure what is running on port 80 you can run this command `lsof -i` on Linux